# On Convexity of product of a convex and a bounded function.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued, $n$-dimensional function defined as follows:

$$
f(\mathbf{x}) = g(\mathbf{x})h(\mathbf{x}),
$$

where $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is **convex**, and $h:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is **bounded**, for instance $h(\mathbf{x})\in[a,b]$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $0<a<b$, $\forall\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

What is true about the **convexity** of $f$? What if $g$ is **quasi-convex**?

Any helpful comment would be nice! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing can be said in general without further conditions on $h$. For instance, if $h(\mathbf{x})=-1$ then $f$ is concave. Even in $n=1$ nothing can be said. Consider for example $g(x)=x^2$ and $h(x)=x$.

Assuming $h$ positive, $0< h(x)< 1$ for instance, does not help. Take for instance $g(x)=1$ and $h(x)=(1+a\sin x)/2$ with $0<a<1$.

Comment: Yeah, let's suppose that $h$ is positive, for instance, $0<h(\mathbf{x})<1$, $\forall \mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. What then?